# Factory class is required while using ExoPlayer

Tags: android, android-studio, exoplayer

Just creating a sample app by including exoplayer library in my app, I have included all the dependencies files and created a instance in my code, it as throwing an error to create a class factory.  Dependencies:

```
 compile 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:r2.4.4'
compile 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:r2.4.4'
compile 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-dash:r2.4.4'
compile 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-ui:r2.4.4'

private ExoPlayer exoPlayer;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    exoPlayer = ExoPlayer.Factory.newInstance(2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `.` before `Factory` in `ExoPlayer.Factory`. Actual class is called [`ExoPlayerFactory`](https://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/ExoPlayerFactory.html).

Comment: Can you refer a simple code to develop a sample audio video player by using exoplayer, As i referred many blogs are using ExoPlayer.Factory to create a new instance.

Comment: @MahalakshmiSaravanan Maybe it's because they use Exoplayer 1 in their tutorial, but not sure. [Here is](https://github.com/ayalus/ExoPlayer-2-Example/blob/27e37e449fc90fcb650ae62590825e31582d2287/ExoPlayer2Example/app/src/main/java/com/ayalus/exoplayer2example/MainActivity.java#L71) where you can find an example of using ExoPlayer 2.